# DB2 Cast return value of cursor

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

the line with fetch will return a VARCHAR, but the values that can be taken are 1 or nothing(NULL). So how can I realize it when I want to do without `SET ANS = (ANSV IS NOT NULL);`

```
DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR S1;
DECLARE ANSV VARCHAR;
DECLARE ANS BOOLEAN;

SET STMT = "SELECT 1 FROM ..."
PREPARE S1 FROM STMT;
OPEN C1;
FETCH FROM C1 INTO ANSV;
CLOSE C1;

SET ANS = (ANSV IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "realize"? If you need some conditional branching then it's `IF ANSV IS NOT NULL THEN ... ELSE ... END IF`. If not, then please describe what you want to do with the result.

Comment: I am searching for a solution to fetch direcly into a bool variable.
In my select clause `SELECT 1 FROM ...` I am doing an existence test.
Can I also say here to get back TRUE or FALSE instead of 1 or null

Comment: Try [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/oo4_zDhp). You get TRUE in the variable, if the result set is not empty, and NULL otherwise.